# Trouble passing tableview cell value to delete cell

Tags: swift, tableview, cell

I am trying to pass a value to update a tableview cell. Problem is I am not able to get the value. The tableview cell code is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;

    // Gets staff name and puts it in the cell title
    var sectionTitle:String = aventurasUnicas.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as String
    var sectionStaff:Array = porAventura[sectionTitle]!
    let staffNic:String = sectionStaff[indexPath.row] as String
    cell.textLabel?.text = staffNic

    // Gets the subtitle
    var subtituloAventura:String = "\(sectionTitle).\(staffNic)" as String
    var sectionStaff2:Array = subtituloTabla[subtituloAventura]!
    let staffNic2:String = sectionStaff2[0] as String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = staffNic2

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DetailButton
    return cell
    }
```

And the code I am stuck with is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // I AM STUCK HERE
    }
}
```

I want to get the staffNic for the next part of the program. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not go this way - the way you get it is the way you set it:

```
let sectionTitle:String = aventurasUnicas.objectAtIndex(indexPath.section) as String
let sectionStaff:Array = porAventura[sectionTitle]!
//the text of the deleted row based on your datasource
let staffNic = sectionStaff[indexPath.row] as String
```

Or get it as cell's text:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
let staffNic = cell.textLabel!.text!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like this:             let cell = tableView?.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)
            let staffNic = cell?.textLabel?.text as String!